# Where do I put the onTouchListener method in an android project?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I've seen plenty of answers on how to use `onTouchListener` such as this code:

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

but it's never clear to me where I'm supposed to put this code in my project ? So far I've only been editing my `MainActivity.java` file, will I need to create another java file to house this code?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Widget properties can just go into your MainActivity code. It should look something like this:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button); //instantiate the button
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {...}) //set the listener
```

The other (less common) way to do this is through XML. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621805/is-it-possible-to-set-event-listener-in-xml) for more on that.

Comment: When I do this i get the error 'Cannot resolve symbol `setOnTouchListener`, any idea why?

Comment: You might be missing imports and/or instantiating incorrectly. Check out [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793152/setontouchlistener-is-giving-me-an-error) for more.